# How to optimise grid allocation according to some constraints

Tags: optimization, grid

Problem:

Given a grid and elements with height 1 and width 2, 3 or 4, determine if a new element with given width (w) and position ((x1,y), (x2,y)) can be allocated so that the grid has (and will have) as less empty cells as possible between existing and future elements.

Constaints:

- You can't move the elements, you can only determine if an element with given position and width can be allocated
- An element with width j has k probability to be allocated in the future, width 2 (high), width 3 (medium), width 4 (low)
- You can't have more than 3 elements with the same x1 or x2
- Minimise the number of empty cells between elements along the x axis

Example of grid:

[image: Example]

The tricky part is that I don't know what elements will be allocated, I can only predict how the grid will be filled based on the probability logic defined above.

I'm looking for an algorithm to solve this problem, any tips appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I dont understand what the "degrees of freedom" are... Can you freely choose `y`? Can you choose `x1`?

Comment: no freedom, I have an element with given position and width and I need to determine if it can be allocated. In other words, I need to write a function which returns True if the element can be allocated, False otherwise.

Comment: ah ok ... but then its not an optimisation task - it's just a 'does it fit in'-test!?

Comment: It's not just a 'does it fit in'-test, I need to predict how the grid will be filled by future allocations based on the probability I mentioned and check if the allocation of the requested element will cause empty cells between future elements. It's an optimisation task because I still need to reject or approve allocations so that at some point in the future the grid will be fully filled.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `Grid` is a 2-dim-array, initialised with `Empty`-Values. A Solution in Python could be:

```
def fitsInGrid(x1,y,w): 
  return all([Grid[x1+x,y] is Empty for x in range(w)])
```

Comment: As I said, it's not just a 'does it fit in'-test, I need to ensure that the grid will have the best configuration at some point in the future. Thanks a lot anyway, I really appreciate it.